# Azure optional claim return object Id - need Group name

Tags: access-token, azure-ad-graph-api, manifest.json, azure-app-registration

i have tried to get user group name as value in auth/me URL, but it returns only objectId of group.
How to get the group name instead of objectId.

In my manifest i have added

"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"

optional claims also added

i don't have any onpremises AD connect
I need the manifest configuration to get the group name in auth/me url

Comment: You can get the all the default properties of group using the Microsoft graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-return-all-default-properties

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this in my lab and it is working for me.
This option is available only if you select "groups assigned to the application" option.

If you select any other option apart from this, "**cloud-only group display names (preview)**" it will be greyed out.

[image]

Since this option is still in preview, there is some enhancements going on at backend.

For more information, you can also refer this documentation [Configure group claims for applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#emit-cloud-only-group-display-name-in-token-preview).

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

[image]

***Manifest:***

[image]

```
"given_name": "kav",
  "groups": [
    "xxxf-94bc-xxxxxx7d",
    "xxxx-2459exx5a"
  ],
```

The jwt cannot contain group name but it  gets  Id’s of the groups

You can customize group claim name following [Configure group claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims)  but it required Onpremise AD which you mentioned is not there as sAMAccountName option is the option present  on Group objects synced from Active Directory.

Else You can check all the default properties using Microsoft graph Api  [Graph Explorer | Try Microsoft Graph APIs - Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

**`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupId>`**

[image]